# Python3 Pandas how to split rows in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

thank you in advance for helping me out.

What I want to learn is how to output each sublist into a cell in csv file
here are my codes

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd

rating = []

#first page
url = 'https://www.yelp.com/biz/madame-vo-new-york'
ourUrl = urllib.request.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(ourUrl,'html.parser')

for i in soup.find_all('li', {'lemon--li__373c0__1r9wz margin-b3__373c0__q1DuY padding-b3__373c0__342DA border--bottom__373c0__3qNtD border-color--default__373c0__3-ifU'}):

    rating.append(re.findall('.*[="](.* star rating).*', str(i)))

rating = '\n'.join(str(line) for line in rating)

df = pd.DataFrame({'reviewRating': [rating]})

df.to_csv('c1.csv', index = False)
```

Here are the output results in 'c1.csv':
[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyHBj.png)

What I want is to look like this:[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUtbb.png)

============same-day update===============

As per SOURAV KUMAR's answer,
after I changed my code to

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'reviewRating': rating})
```

Here is the result:[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1cwb.png)
Which is still not what it shows in "image2"

Comment: I don't understand, what is the difference between output 1 and output 2?

Comment: Remove this line of code:
`rating = '\n'.join(str(line) for line in rating)`

and then make the change as per SOURAV's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, there is just one change that can be done here :

Instead of this :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'reviewRating': [rating]})
```

write :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'reviewRating': rating})
```

Then, pandas will directly create series of all elements in different rows instead of taking all of it as in one row.

Output :

```
>>> df
       reviewRating
0   [5 star rating]
1   [4 star rating]
2   [4 star rating]
3   [2 star rating]
4   [5 star rating]
5   [4 star rating]
6   [5 star rating]
7   [3 star rating]
8   [5 star rating]
9   [5 star rating]
10  [4 star rating]
11  [4 star rating]
12  [5 star rating]
13  [5 star rating]
14  [5 star rating]
15  [4 star rating]
16  [5 star rating]
17  [5 star rating]
18  [5 star rating]
19  [4 star rating]
```

Comment: Hi SOURAV, thanks for your answer, I still have problem after I changed my codes based on your suggestion, I updated my reason on the post, would you please take a look at it? Thanks!